# How to distinguish between component instances in Vue Devtools

Tags: vue.js

When I look at my application state in Vue's devtools chrome extension, I can see multiple instances of the same component in the tree view.  However, there is no way to distinguish one instance from another.  For example, in the screenshot below there are three `<Todo>` components.  Imagine instead there are 30.  How do I attach some kind of instance name or id to my components?  It seems silly to have to click through 30 components to find the one I need.  [image: Sample screenshot showing vue devtools tree view]

Comment: If there is no way at the moment it would be useful to open an issue on the github repo https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues maybe they will add it in the future.

Comment: How would you prefer something like this work? A hash map of component `name`'s to `prop` to show along side of it? `Vue.config.devtoolsComponentIdentifierMap = { Todo: 'id' }` Then get something like `<Todo 342> || <Todo "foo"> || `<Todo {someObj: foo}>` in the inspector?

Comment: i don't know if it's a good solution but you may do that `this.$options.name = 'todo ' + this.todo.someProp` in your component `mounted` method

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN - I'm too new to Vue to know if it's a good solution, but that does meet my immediate need.

Comment: @BillCriswell I think that would definitely work for my use case, and be more reusable than ABDEL's method, which works in a pinch but requires adding code to each component you want the extra details on.

Comment: Maybe even do `Component -> {KeyDirective}`.
so if you wanted it named just have to include a `key='value'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same idea also a couple of months ago.

So I gave it a try.

My PR has been submitted: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/pull/331

It's probably a bit early to rely on my solution since the core team could still reject the PR or request other naming conventions.

Until then you can build my proposal version yourself from my repo:
https://github.com/nerdyglasses/vue-devtools/tree/verbose-component-tree

Is that helping you?

Best, Christian

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ':key' attribute. And you even HAVE TO use it if your  component depends on a v-for loop.

[here you can see the keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71EBF.png)